# Create dynamic Year-Month headers based on a start Year - Google Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Is there a way to create a `single header row of 12 dynamic Year-Month columns` (formatted `yyyy-mmm`) using `Google Query`? These dates should change based on a Year selection in say, Cell `C1`. e.g. C1 could have values like 2016,2017,2018,2019,2020.

Example with formulas e.g.

```
=arrayformula(EDATE(date(C1,1,1),SEQUENCE(1,12,)))
```

or

```
=Arrayformula(EOMONTH(date(C1,1,1),SEQUENCE(1,12,)))
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer as I don't think it adds anything to yours. I will leave as a comment that you might make the formula a little shorter using =ArrayFormula(date(C1,sequence(1,12),1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to formulate the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(EDATE(date(C1,1,1),SEQUENCE(1,12,)))),"SELECT Col1 LABEL Col1 'DATES' FORMAT Col1 'yyyy-mmm'")))
```

anyone has a shorter way, do let me know.

#### Edit:

Alternatively, a shorter version, suggested by [Tom Sharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263579/create-dynamic-year-month-headers-based-on-a-start-year-google-query#comment115397356_65263579):

```
=ArrayFormula(date(C1,sequence(1,12),1))
```